# How to xmlstarlet on multiple files in different paths?

Tags: xml, linux, unix, xmlstarlet

I am using C Shell.

My working directory:

```
cd /mnt/FusionOATS/CRM/Research/rys/
```

My Current Working xmlstarlet command (does an xmlstarlet operation on 2 files which are directly under the working directory and the result is pasted in an output text file):

```
foreach xmlfile ( ResultReport1.xml ResultReport2.xml )
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl "$xmlfile" >> /scratch/rys/view_storage/outroo3.txt
end
```

Now I need to this on files which are in different paths like below:

- Working Directory/ResultReport1.xml
- Working Directory/ResultReport.xml
- Working Directory/Test3/ResultReport3.xml

I tried this:

```
foreach xmlfile ( ResultReport1.xml ResultReport2.xml /Test3/ResultReport3.xml )
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl "$xmlfile" >> /scratch/rys/view_storage/outroo4.txt
end
```

But, getting the below error:

failed to load external entity "/Test3/ResultReport2.xml"

Can I do this with xmlstarlet? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removing the slash at the start of the file path resolved the error:

This worked:

```
foreach xmlfile ( ResultReport1.xml ResultReport2.xml Test3/ResultReport2.xml )
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl "$xmlfile" >> /scratch/rys/view_storage/outroo4.txt
end
```

Comment: I hope you understand what the slash means, at least.